# While going for extra loop

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following code to loop through a question session with a user:

```
#loop counter
COUNTER=1

# Initial question

echo ""
echo -n "Would you like a cup of tea? (y/n)" # Ask initial question
read answer # Check answer

while [ $COUNTER -le 5 ] # while counter is less than or equal to 5

do
        if [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ]; then # if answer is 'y'
                echo "" # skip a line for cleanliness
                echo "Great, I'll make it now" # Satisfaction
                echo ""
                break # End the loop
        else # if answer is anything other than 'y'
                echo "" # skip a line for cleanliness
                echo -n "Are you sure? (y/n)" # Ask again
                read answer # Check the answer again
                let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 # increment COUNTER
        fi

done # finish
```

The code should act as follows:

1. Ask user if they would like tea.
2. If user says yes, then print out something, and end loop
3. If user says no, go for another 4 attempts before ending loop.
4. If user says yes, after saying no, print out something, and end loop.

The code works fine for points 1,2, and 4.
On point 3 - the code loops to a 5th loop before ending.

I can't seem to be able to identify the error.

Edit: Changed to COUNTER = 0, and $COUNTER -le 4. However, code doesn't implement point 4, on 4th attempt (i.e. 1 initial no, followed by 3 extra nos, before a yes).

Comment: Changing `while [ $COUNTER -le 5 ]` to `while [ $COUNTER -le 4 ]` fixed the issue atleast for me.

Comment: ... or `[ $COUNTER -lt 5 ]` ("less than" vs. "less than or equal").

Comment: If you're going to use bashisms like `echo -n` and `let`, you may as well use ones that will make your code simpler as well, like `for ((counter=1; counter < 5; counter++)); do` and `if [[ $answer = [Yy]* ]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply limit counter to less than 5, instead of less than or equal to.

Use `-lt` instead of `-le`. That is `[ $COUNTER -lt 5]`

OR

You can say less than or equal to 4 and thus you can maintain `[ $COUNTER -le 4]`

Comment: suggested solution is based on COUNTER starting at 1, but if it is initialized to 0, then it should be set to less than or equal to 3 ( `-le 3`), so that it will run through 0,1,2,3 (4 steps) or it can be maintained to be `-lt 4`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 2 lines,

`echo -n "Are you sure? (y/n)" # Ask again
 read answer # Check the answer again`

you can shorten it to one:

`read -p "Are you sure? (y/n): " answer`

However, I'm not entirely sure by what you mean by point 4. Could you provide an example or a little more description?